# Why i need to mask and frame the data if it is possible to send the data as plain text in WebSocket javascript?

Tags: javascript, sockets, http, tcp, websocket

I am a beginner and learning to **WebSocket** javascript. After learning the basics, I created a simple **WebSocket** based chat application, used php **Socket Extension** on the server side, and successfully did the handshake. But after the handshake, I am unable to send and receive the data, so, for this reason, I start further research and found in the RFC that the data should be masked and should be sent as a frame, Ok fine, then I started to learn about the masking and framing the data.

But one thing shocked me on youtube tutorial, where the tutor is sending and receiving the data without any masking and framing process, and he is sending the data as plain text in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0U9wykZhDcY).

So, whether it is also possible to send the data as a plain text, if yes then why I am unable to send the data as a plain text. Or maybe there is something that I am missing, or maybe I am watching the outdated video tutorial. Please, can anyone tell what is the scenario in easy words?

Thanks !!!

Comment: I'm guessing the browser `WebSocket` interface just abstracts those details so you don't have to worry about it. The spec says that only clients must mask the data, servers should send the data unmasked.

Comment: Then why this guy in the video is sending the plain text without any masking, and he successfully receives the data on the server.

Comment: Like I said, the interface is most likely doing it for him. You see him using the interface with unmasked strings but that doesn't mean that the text is being sent as plain text (without a mask).

Comment: So, you mean that the masking and framing is done by the browser automatically by the browser?

Comment: Like I said, most likely. You could take a look at [`ws`](https://github.com/websockets/ws). They have a client and server implementation for NodeJS. Their send method takes the payload without unmasking but they send the message masked.

Comment: Yes you are right, he is using modules in Nodejs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182280/discussion-between-daddy-boy-and-minusfour).